# Auto-deleting paste-bins, preferably with file upload

Tags: pastebin

I'm hunting for a pastebin, the features I want the most, are auto-delete, enabled by default,, and file upload , so I can upload images. Bonus points if it allows me to secure the paste from prying eyes.